# Access Control Origin Headers in Angular 4 App

Tags: angular, rest, http, playframework, cors

I have a Play framework based REST API running locally on my machine on post 9000. I have an Angular 4 app running on port 4200 also on localhost.

I would like this Angular app to display the JSON that I get from the REST API. I tried it on Chrome, but the Angular app could not display the JSON from the Play server and it shows the following message in the browser console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9000/powerPlant/4/details. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.
```

So what do I do in this case?

Comment: This is a CORS error. See this: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#requesting-services-from-a-different-server-cors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok! This is what I did to solve this! In my Play framework application, I added the header to every API endpoint!

```
  implicit class ResultExtensions (result: Result) {
    def withHeaders =  result.withHeaders(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" -> "*"
      , "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" -> "OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, HEAD"   
      , "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" -> "Accept, Content-Type, Origin, X-Json, X-Prototype-Version, X-Requested-With" //, "X-My-NonStd-Option"
      , "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" -> "true"
    )
  }
```

In the places where I return the response, I add the headers!

```
Ok("The API is ready").withHeaders
```

This is soft of ugly, but I guess I will move this adding headers to probably a filter!